# how to use jsp tag expression in <html:select>?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to display dropdown on the basis of if condition,My code snippet is as below

```
 <%if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {String user=(String)session.getAttribute("executorname"); %>
            <html:select style="width:190;" value="<%=user%>" property="jobOwner">
                <html:option value="<%=user %>"><%=user %></html:option>
            </html:select>
            <%} %>
```

I get `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/frmQueryExecutor.jsp(73,23) quote symbol expected`

I want the value os session variable in dropdown.

Comment: Why don't you quote the tag attribute values?

Comment: Please see edited post.Even after adding quotes in value ,I am getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way,

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.executorname}"> //if loop
     <html:select style="width:190;" value="<%=user%>" property="jobOwner">
         <html:option value="${sessionScope.executorname}"><${sessionScope.executorname}></html:option>
     </html:select>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise> // else loop
      //do whatever
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

and try to avoid scriplets all together.